# Is it possible to feed a model in Keras Tuner with tensor data instead of features and labels numpy arrays?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Machine Learning model that I want to do Hyper parameter tunnning on. The data used in this model is pre-processed using tensorflow data tensors and I have already shuffled and batched the data in the tensors. This works fine while fitting the model. I have tried to retrieve the inner numpy arrays to feed the model in kt, but I want to know if it's possible to use the tensors in kt

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use Tensors in Keras Tuner. Please refer the Tensorflow Blog, https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/01/hyperparameter-tuning-with-keras-tuner.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [Tensorflow Support](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11530462/tensorflow-support) for the answer in the comment. Specifying the answer in the answer section for the benefit of the community.

> Yes, it is possible to use Tensors in Keras Tuner. Please refer the
> Tensorflow Blog, [Hyperparameter tuning with Keras Tuner](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/01/hyperparameter-tuning-with-keras-tuner.html).